# WSL Bash isn't finding java in PATH

Tags: java, linux, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have an export command in my .bashrc to add the path of the java.exe file to PATH. Right now, running echo $PATH gives me this at the end

```
/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-14.0.2/bin
```

This is exactly where the java.exe and javac.exe files are stored, but when I run something like
`java -version` I'm getting the `Command 'java' not found` error. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

You have added the *Windows* version of the Java binaries to the Path. You use WSL to run *Linux* binaries. (WSL1 is a compatibility layer, WSL2 uses the Linux kernel).

You have two options:

1. Install Java in your WSL environment. For example on Ubuntu with following commands:

   ```sh
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install openjdk-14-jdk
   ```

   After installing Java it will be available in the search path.
2. You could also run the Windows version by calling `java.exe` (note the `.exe`) on the name. This way WSL would call the Windows version. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop#run-windows-tools-from-linux)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the windows version of java for some reason you where almost there. Try this please :)

```
java.exe -version
```

Answer (score 0):

Install java in wsl:

```
sudo apt-get -y install openjdk-14-jdk
```

check the version.

```
java –version
```

check the path to config JAVA_HOME.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

eg

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/java.
```

edit environment file to add the path:

```
   sudo nano /etc/environment
```

add declare and add the JAVA_HOME:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$JAVA_HOME/bin" 

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64
```

save and check the path.

```
source /etc/environment 

echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Output

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64
```